# Google BigQuery JOINING between 3 Tables

Tags: google-bigquery

```
SELECT
  C. cdrs_id AS cdrs_id,
  C. cdrs_cc_card AS cdrs_cc_card,
  C. cdrs_starttime AS cdrs_starttime,
  C. cdrs_sessiontime AS cdrs_sessiontime,
  S. login_source AS login_source
FROM
  [Dataset.Statistics_Application] AS S 
JOIN EACH [Dataset.User_Info] AS U ON  S. user_id = U. id 
JOIN EACH [Dataset.CDRSTrafficDB] AS C ON U. vcard = C. cdrs_cc_card AND C. cdrs_starttime BETWEEN S. start_date AND S. end_date
GROUP BY
  cdrs_id,
  cdrs_cc_card,
  cdrs_starttime,
  cdrs_sessiontime,
  login_source
```

There is a way to write each join with `=` condition and `between` condition. 
**Error: ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name.**

Comment: Did you tried anything?  And where do you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

[Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) in BigQuery does not have this limitation. You can use a query of this form; note the difference in table name escaping and the removal of `EACH`:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  C. cdrs_id AS cdrs_id,
  C. cdrs_cc_card AS cdrs_cc_card,
  C. cdrs_starttime AS cdrs_starttime,
  C. cdrs_sessiontime AS cdrs_sessiontime,
  S. login_source AS login_source
FROM
  `Dataset.Statistics_Application` AS S 
JOIN `Dataset.User_Info` AS U ON  S. user_id = U. id 
JOIN `Dataset.CDRSTrafficDB` AS C ON U. vcard = C. cdrs_cc_card AND C. cdrs_starttime BETWEEN S. start_date AND S. end_date
GROUP BY
  cdrs_id,
  cdrs_cc_card,
  cdrs_starttime,
  cdrs_sessiontime,
  login_source
```